# MS Excel: How do you modify the default hyperlink color?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, styles, templates

I have an existing "dark mode" Excel template, which I created one year ago.

[image: Picture of current template styles]

I don't remember exactly how I created the template, because it's been so long - but *I think* I simply modified the `normal` text style and the default table style.

While I'm rusty on Excel templates, and I don't exactly remember how I created this one - I have been using this template extensively, and I would like to add one more modification.

I'd like to change the default color Excel uses with creating hyperlinks.
Is there a place I can change this value globally? (for the entire workbook template, all worksheets, new worksheets, etc.)

***EDIT:***
Apparently I don't have a "Hyperlink" style available to modify?
I have no idea why this would be the case ... if anyone has any insight, that would be very helpful.
[image: Picture of available styles]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit a Template's Hyperlink Cell Settings:

1. Right click the template file and choose **Open**.

   - The default action of double clicking a template file is to create a *New* workbook
     based on the template, and therefore, not the desired action.
2. Add a temporary hyperlink to a cell in the template workbook.
   A. Follow the hyperlink once to enable *"Modify" - "Followed Hyperlink"* in step 4B.
3. Select the temporary hyperlink cell with a long press (yes, that's a pc thing too)

   - or navigate to the cell with the keyboard or using the address box
   - or click the cell but not the link (avoid following the hyperlink)
4. Modify the color for the hyperlink:
   A. **Home** (tab) | **Styles** (section) | **Cell Styles**
   B. ***Right click*** either **Hyperlink** or **Followed Hyperlink**
   [image]
   C. Select **Modify** and make the desired changes.
   D. Repeat step 4B (see 2A to enable *"Followed..."*) to edit both.
5. Delete the contents of the cell with the temporary hyperlink.
6. Save this template file or *Save as* a template file: *.xlt .xltx .xltm*

Source: [Microsoft Support - Change the Font Format for Hyperlinks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-font-format-for-hyperlinks-672c2905-ad3e-40be-b281-811e68386243)
*Section: Save Hyperlink Cell Styles for Future Workbooks*

Comment: I don't see the "Hyperlink" style in my list ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uikj.png

Comment: @CompellingArgument: from your screenshot sends you try to edit a workbook (book1) and not the template.

Comment: @MátéJuhász That's the only way I know how to edit templates - open the template (it automatically opens a new workbook), make changes, "Save As" and change the file type from `XLSX` to `XLTX`

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to _create_ a hyperlink in a cell, before the style option would appear. Also, clicking on the hyperlink, causes the `Followed Hyperlink` style option to appear as well (which I will also modify).